# How to fix Lombok coverage in a multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, lombok, multi-module

I have a project with multiple maven modules and each of them have unit tests implemented. They depend on each other through a parent module. I'm using Lombok to generate all boiler-plate code for my models and, through the unit tests, i'm not covering the @Getters and @Setters on these models.

I'm aware that, to exclude these and improve your coverage, you can add a lombok.config with the setting `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true`. I added this in the parent module but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to configure this for all modules?

I also tried to add different lombok.config files across all modules and it still didn't work. This issue mostly affects SonarQube coverage, as it is not aware that it should ignore these unused getters and setters.

PS: Before being a multi-module project, the project was a simple maven project and this lombok.config worked, the coverage was good. Nothing was changed in the unit tests after moving the project to a multi-modules approach.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that your intention is to cover all methods (including those generated with lombok annotations) except for the getters and setters?

Comment: I think your mistake is to assume, that changing the lombok config of the parent project will in any way affect the outcome of class generation of the dependant projects. This is not the case. Lombok will only look for a lombok.config within the respective project itself (https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration). Class files generated by a "child" project will be built disregarding the configuration within the "parent".

Comment: @TreffnonX no, my intention is not that. The unit test cover all business logic in the services, which don't use the getters and setters in the models at all, and thus, sonar complains about this in the coverage percentage. I know that this is solvable by configuring Lombok with this config file but this doesn't seem to work when there are multiple maven modules...

Answer (score 3):

Any `lombok.config` file will only affect java-files within that directory or below. Having a config-file in a superproject will not affect files in child projects or modules, unless those source-paths are below that of the parent project, which I assume is not the case.

The line `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true` needs to be in every `lombok.config`-file within each source directory to be affected.